# Truncate beginning of string with str.format

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, format

I'd like to allign a string to the right but have its beginning be truncated instead of its end.

I tried this:

```
my_str = '01234567890'
print "{0:>4.4}".format(my_str)
```

Output:

```
'0123'
```

Desidered Output:

```
'7890'
```

Is there a way to do this with `format` or do I have to cut the string before feeding it?

Comment: you just want this output:'7890'?

Comment: why not just `"{0}".format(my_str[-4:])`?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was thinking:`my_str[-4:]`

Comment: My questions is exactly that, do I HAVE to truncate it myself and then feed it to fomat OR is there a way to do it with format?

Comment: @izxle Nope. It is mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) that *For non-number types the field indicates the maximum field size - in other words, how many characters will be used from the field content.* So you will hafta truncate it in the beginning itself

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I didn't try that because I thought with `my_str[-4]` you would get an error if the string didn't have at least 4 elements but now I checked and it doesn't. Thanks, will use this.

Comment: @izxle,  you would get an error with `my_str[-4]` bit not with `my_str[-4:]` i.e slicing

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, yeah, I forgot to add the colon there. It's working now, thanks.

Comment: Oh dear, @Padraic you have again forgotten to write an answer here :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the reverse of the string as input and reverse again the output.

```
my_str = "01234567890"
new_str = "{:4.4}".format(my_str[::-1])
desired_output = new_str[::-1]

print(my_str[::-1])
print(new_str)
print(desired_output)
```

Output:

```
09876543210
0987
7890
```

Note that a more complex way is described [here (StackOverflow question 37974565)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974565/left-truncate-using-python-3-5-str-format), which offers a solution if the input string may not be changed (substring, reverse).