# Left truncate using python 3.5 str.format?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

*Q: Is is possible to create a format string using Python 3.5's string formatting syntax to left truncate?*

Basically what I want to do is take a git SHA:

```
"c1e33f6717b9d0125b53688d315aff9cf8dd9977"
```

And using only a format string, get the display only the right 8 chars:

```
"f8dd9977"
```

Things Ive tried:

**Invalid Syntax**

```
>>> "{foo[-8:]}".format(foo="c1e33f6717b9d0125b53688d315aff9cf8dd9977")
>>> "{foo[-8]}".format(foo="c1e33f6717b9d0125b53688d315aff9cf8dd9977")  
>>> "{:8.-8}".format("c1e33f6717b9d0125b53688d315aff9cf8dd9977")
```

**Wrong Result**

```
### Results in first 8 not last 8. 
>>> "{:8.8}".format("c1e33f6717b9d0125b53688d315aff9cf8dd9977")
```

**Works but inflexible and cumbersome**

```
### solution requires that bar is always length of 40.
>>> bar="c1e33f6717b9d0125b53688d315aff9cf8dd9977"
>>> "{foo[32]}{foo[33]}{foo[34]}{foo[35]}{foo[36]}{foo[37]}{foo[38]}{foo[39]}".format(foo=bar)
```

A similar question was [asked, but never answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721292/truncate-beginning-of-string-with-str-format). However mine differs in that I am limited to using only format string, I don't have the ability to change the range of the input param.  This means that the following is an unacceptable solution:

```
>>> bar="c1e33f6717b9d0125b53688d315aff9cf8dd9977"
>>> "{0}".format(bar[-8:])
```

One more aspect I should clarify... the above explains the simplest form of the problem.  In actual context, the problem is expressed more correctly as:

```
>>> import os
>>> "foo {git_sha}".format(**os.environ)
```

Where I want to left_truncate "git_sha" environment variable. Admittedly this is a tad more complex than simplest form, but if I can solve the simplest - I can find a way to solve the more complex.

Comment: If the input is a string, what is preventing you from slicing off the last `8` characters before the format?

Comment: In python 3.6 it will be as simple as  `f'{s[-8:]}'`

Comment: @arewm basically I have a config file which is a template and I can substitute environment variables into the titles.  Altering the environment is just a bunch of work... it would be easier if I could solve via formatting.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That would be reasonable... but only at Python 3.5 :-(

Comment: @JacquesGaudin you've missed the point... format string only...

Comment: Just throwing this out there - not sure if it would work and it is still rigid/cumbersome: `'{foo[32]}{foo[33]}{foo[34]}{foo[35]}{foo[36]}{foo[37]}{foo[38]}{foo[39]}'.format(foo='{foo:>40}'.format(foo=text))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclassing `str` and overriding the `__format__` method is an option:

```
class CustomStr(str):
    def __format__(self, spec):
        if spec == 'trunc_left':
            return self[-8:]
        else:
            return super().__format__(spec)

git_sha = 'c1e33f6717b9d0125b53688d315aff9cf8dd9977'
s = CustomStr(git_sha)

print('{:trunc_left}'.format(s))
```

Better though, you can create a custom `Formatter` which inherits from [`string.Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter) and will provide a `format` method. By doing this, you can override a number of methods used in the process of formatting strings. In your case, you want to override `format_field`:

```
from string import Formatter

class CustomFormatter(Formatter):
        
     def format_field(self, value, format_spec):
         if format_spec.startswith('trunc_left.'):
             char_number = int(format_spec[len('trunc_left.'):])
             return value[-char_number:]
         return super().format_field(value, format_spec)

environ = {'git_sha': 'c1e33f6717b9d0125b53688d315aff9cf8dd9977'}
fmt = CustomFormatter()
print(fmt.format('{git_sha:trunc_left.8}', **environ))
```

Depending on the usage, you could put this in a context manager and temporarily shadow the builtin `format` function:

```
from string import Formatter

class CustomFormat:
    
    class CustomFormatter(Formatter):
        
        def format_field(self, value, format_spec):
            if format_spec.startswith('trunc_left.'):
                char_number = int(format_spec[len('trunc_left.'):])
                return value[-char_number:]
            return super().format_field(value, format_spec)
            
    def __init__(self):
        self.custom_formatter = self.CustomFormatter()
            
    def __enter__(self):
        self.builtin_format = format
        return self.custom_formatter.format
        
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        # make sure global format is set back to the original
        global format
        format = self.builtin_format

    
environ = {'git_sha': 'c1e33f6717b9d0125b53688d315aff9cf8dd9977'}

with CustomFormat() as format:
    # Inside this context, format is our custom formatter's method
    print(format('{git_sha:trunc_left.8}', **environ))

print(format)  # checking that format is now the builtin function
```

Comment: So maybe the question then is can one overload `str` with `CustomStr` by doing a `str=CustomStr` or `basestring=CustomStr`?

Comment: Answer edited according to the `os.environ` requirement. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm giving @JacquesGaudin the answer since it was the most helpful.  I didn't want to subclass str or dict, but used his solution to build my own as listed in the answer list.

Answer (score 1):

So here is my solution, with thanks to @JacquesGaudin and folks on #Python for providing much guidance...

```
class MyStr(object):
    """Additional format string options."""
    def __init__(self, obj):
        super(MyStr, self).__init__()
        self.obj = obj

    def __format__(self, spec):
        if spec.startswith("ltrunc."):
            offset = int(spec[7:])
            return self.obj[offset:]
        else:
            return self.obj.__format__(spec)
```

So this works when doing this:

```
>>> f = {k: MyStr(v) for k, v in os.environ.items()} 
>>> "{PATH:ltrunc.-8}".format(**f)
```

Comment: Looks good. If I may, I would pass the offset as a positive integer and add the minus sign when doing the slicing but it's a matter of detail. Well done.

Comment: I think I will leave as is... there are cases where I still want the same left truncation, but know the offset from the beginning of the `str` as opposed to the end.