# Truncate last n characters in a string using .format()

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to truncate last 100 chars of a string using .format() and add another 100 chars long string. I thought this should be the most obvious and pythonic way:

```
print('{:.-100}{:100}'.format(str1, str2))
```

But it doesn't work.

I can achieve it this way:

```
print('{}{:100}'.format(str1[:-100], str2))
```

But I don't think it's beautiful or readable code. Of course, I can use .replace() and .strip() and .ljust() but...

So am I missing something in my original broken code? Or shall I stay with the second one? Or will it be the most pythonic way to use .replace() etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
print('{}{}'.format(str1[:-100], str2[:100]))
```

At least that way, you will be consistent.

If you want other ways to do it, this question might help: [Left truncate using python 3.5 str.format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974565/left-truncate-using-python-3-5-str-format) .

Answer (score 0):

If I was at your place, I would accept the second one. It looks readable to me. I always truncate strings like how you did.